# Output of the Program?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int fun(int, int);
typedef int (*pf) (int, int);
int proc(pf, int, int);

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", proc(fun, 6, 6));
    return 0;
}
int fun(int a, int b)
{
   return (a==b);
}
int proc(pf p, int a, int b)
{
   return ((*p)(a, b));
}
```

// direct link of program : http://codepad.org/fBIPiHGT

Comment: direct link of program : http://codepad.org/fBIPiHGT ... i didn't get how the output is 1 ..

Comment: It's 1. Just as it should be. So?

Comment: What's the question/problem ?
It just looks like a very complicated way to compare two integers.

Comment: @Cedric: My guess is he's trying function pointers.

Comment: @0A0D My guess is he's getting us to do his homework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program's output is:

```
1
```

Ok, so let's see what's going on there.

```
#include<stdio.h>
```

This line just include standard input/output functionality.

```
int fun(int, int);
```

This tells the compiler: Ok, we have a function named `fun` taking two `int` variables, returning an `int`.

```
typedef int (*pf) (int, int);
```

This installs kinda shortcut for a pointer to a function taking two `int` variables returning `int`, so this kind of function pointer can be abbreviated using `pf`.

```
int proc(pf, int, int);
```

Tells the compiler: Ok, we have a function named `proc` taking a `pf` variable (which is - like we saw above - a function pointer to a function taking two `int` variables returning an `int`), two `int` variables, returning an `int`.

```
int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", proc(fun, 6, 6));
    return 0;
}
```

The central procedure that's run when the program is executed. It tells the program to print a number (`%d`) and a newline (`\n`). The number shall have the value of `proc(fun,6,6)`.

```
int fun(int a, int b)
{
   return (a==b);
}
```

Here we have what function `fun` is supposed to do. This function compares `a` and `b`, returns 1 if they're equal, 0 otherwise (just the definition of results of `==` in C).

```
int proc(pf p, int a, int b)
{
   return ((*p)(a, b));
}
```

Here we have what `proc` actually does: It takes a function pointer (which is - as we saw above - ...) `p` and two ints. Then it calls the given function (`p`) applied to the two arguments given (`a` and `b`) and returns `p`'s result.

So, if we call `proc(fun, 6, 6)`, `proc` will call `fun(6,6)`, which evaluates to 1 (since `6==6`) and returns this result (`1`).

So, the output will be just

```
1
```

**But honestly:** Please have a look at some things and try to figure out things yourself before just asking (why is the output this-and-that):

- http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html: Function pointers

Comment: Great effort. Many devs who have skipped assembler have conceptual problems with a function pointer as a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Type pf is a function type. In main(), function fun is passed to function proc, so:

```
proc(fun, 6, 6) = fun(6, 6) = 6==6 = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 printf("%d\n", proc(fun, 6, 6));
```

Outputs the result of proc as an **int**.

```
 return ((*p)(a, b));
```

Returns the result of running `p(a,b)`, ergo `fun(6,6)`

```
 return (a==b);
```

`6 == 6` returns `true`, casted to an **int** equals **1**.

All because of:

```
int(true) == 1
```

As for the line:

```
return ((*p)(a, b));
```

... is the same as:

```
return (*p)(a, b);
```

What we are doing here is dereferencing the function pointer `p` so a call can be made with the passed parameters. The `(*p)` is the dereferenced pointer, and the `(a, b)` are the parameters. `p` points to `fun`, so `*p` is `fun`.

Comment: typedef int (*pf) (int, int);

wt happens in this process ?

Comment: @Vishwanath, I expanded my answer.

Comment: It defines "pf" as a pointer to a function returning int, that takes two ints as parameters.

Comment: thanks friend .. nw i got it .. really thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
1
```

Function Pointer to "fun" is passed to proc, which evalutes 6==6, returns true, which is converted impliclty to "1".

http://codepad.org/uRbOnkXb

Answer (score 0):

It is returning `true` (AKA 1). Since you are returning an int, the `boolean` value is being implicitly converted from `true` to `1`. Program is operating correctly. 6 equals 6 which yields true or 1.

Comment: I know .. answer is 1 .. bt how i didn't get how the function is calling and tycasting process. plz if u know explain .

Comment: because you are passing address to the fun function into your proc function and the compiler knows what fun is so it calls it when you say `return ((*p)(a, b));`

Comment: @Vish: See also http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter5/function_pointers.html

Comment: thanks thanks link... really useful.. dude . can u provide me useful websites where i can solve . C programs,problems to gain more knowledge .. in C programming

Comment: @Vish: You're on one now :) Recommend you go to the book store or Amazon.com and purchase some programming books and teach yourself.. take some college courses, etc