# meaning of this code

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
 int x = 2, y = 6, z = 6;
 x = y == z;
 printf("%d", x);
}
```

Comment: "output for the following"? Well, just run the program and you'll see the output... one assumes you mean "Why do I get the output that I do?" - well, in this case see Potatoswatter's answer.

Answer (score 3):

`==` has higher precedence than `=`, and `y==z` is `1`.

I will end the answer there, because this looks like homework.

Answer (score 2):

http://codepad.org/fp4ZYJX5

Answer (score 1):

The output is:

```
1
```

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594973/output-of-the-program/3594991#3594991), which explains a similar, yet more complex question and will answer yours as well.

Comment: +1- I call it time saving tactics.

Answer (score 0):

Output is 1

If you want more help we can give you