# Question about x=y==z

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int x = 2, y = 6, z = 6;
    x = y == z;
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

output is = 1

Why?

Comment: the result of the == is a boolean and true = 1.

Comment: Do you know the guy who asked this question - are you two from the same class? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598977/meaning-of-this-code-closed

Comment: Yes it's a simple question. Maybe it deserves to be closed but the least we can do for the community is provide a link to the appropriate language reference.  We don't want to end up with lots of these dead-end questions.  If they point somewhere, at least the PageRank effect of the link increases the likelihood of better search results.

Answer (score 4):

Because the assignment is right to left, and the precedence of == is greater than =.

it is x = (y == z)

y == z is 1.

Answer (score 2):

From the [precedence table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) `==` is having a higher precedence from `=`

Hence

```
x = y == z;
```

is same as:

```
x = (y == z);
```

Since `y == z` is true (1), `x` gets `1`.

Answer (score 1):

`x = y == z` is read as `x = (y == z)`, and y and z both are 6 and thus they are equal. `true` is 1, so x is 1.

Answer (score 1):

`y == z` evaluates to true, which you are assigning to `x`...`x = true` casts to a value of 1 because `x` is of type `int`.

Comment: There is no cast, right? Tagged as C and C does not have a boolean type.

Comment: Oh, you are both wrong. C *does* have a boolean type, yet there is no cast here.

Answer (score 1):

y == z => 6 == 6 => True

True represented as integer (%d) is 1.

Answer (score 0):

`x = y == z;` is the same thing as `x = (y == z);` and as `y == 6` and `z == 6`, `(y == z) == 1` so `x == 1`

Answer (score 0):

It evals == operator first, so since y==z is true, and x is int,x is set to 1 (true)

Answer (score 0):

Comparison (`==`) has higher precedence than assignment (`=`), so your middle statement is processed as `x = ( y == z )`; and the result of a true comparison is 1, which is assigned to x.

Answer (score 0):

== have higher precedence than =. So x = y == z is actually x = (y == z). Now y and z both are 6. So the comparison is true and outcome is 1 which is set to x.